# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout App closing when it is creating inflater in Adapter

Tags: android, retrofit, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Trying to create a RecyclerView and filling data with Retrofit2 in Fragment
but when I run app and go to that fragment it closes,

when I debug App is closing in following lines of Adapter's **onCreateViewHolder**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
```

It's giving following error

```
RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Following is Fragment's Code

```
ApiConfig apiConfig = AppConfig.getRetrofit().create(ApiConfig.class);
            Call<List<TCImages>> call = apiConfig.getImages();
            call.enqueue( new Callback<List<TCImages>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<TCImages>> call, Response<List<TCImages>> response) {
                    tcImages = response.body();

                    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById( R.id.recyclerView );
                    manager = new LinearLayout( getContext() );
                    tcAdapter = new TCAdapter( tcImages, getActivity() );
                    recyclerView.setAdapter( tcAdapter );
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<TCImages>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            } );
```

Below is my Adapter's code

```
package com.example.tc;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.tc.networking.TCImages;

import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


public class TCAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TCAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    List<TCImages> tcImages;
    Context context;

    public TCAdapter(List<TCImages> tcImages, FragmentActivity activity){
        this.tcImages = tcImages;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
        View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.item_tc_recycler, parent, false );
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText( tcImages.get( position ).getEmail() );

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tcImages.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super( itemView );
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.txtItem );
        }
    }
}
```

I am in learning phase and I am getting codes for Activity and i am converting them in Fragment.

Comment: I don't know why FragmentActivity activity is not working in Adapter's Constructor, I changed it according to you and passed the getContext while calling Adapter and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever set value for `Context context;`?

Probably you want to do like this:

```
public TCAdapter(List<TCImages> tcImages, Context context){
        this.tcImages = tcImages;
        this.context = context;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why FragmentActivity activity is not working in Adapter's Constructor, I changed it according to you and passed the getContext while calling Adapter and it worked. Do you have any Idea why it wasn't working?

Comment: Basically, the parameter type is different. You need a `Context` in your Adapter, so I changed your constructor to accept a `Context` type.

Answer (score 1):

Get the context from the parent.

```
 View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.car_row_layout, parent, false)
```

or pass the context from the fragment or activity in the adapter constructor, u just declare the context but not initialize there is problem

```
List<TCImages> tcImages;
    Context context;

    public TCAdapter(List<TCImages> tcImages, FragmentActivity activity){
        this.tcImages = tcImages;
    }
```